# StreamReader using arraylist or array

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, streamreader

Here's my code:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("war.txt");
string input = null;

while ((input = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input);
}

reader.Close();
```

The program above reads and prints out from the file “war.txt” line-by-line. I need to re-write the program so that it prints out in reverse order, i.e., last line first and first line last. For example, if “war.txt” contains the following:

```
Hello.

How are you?

Thank you.

Goodbye.
```

The program should prints out:

```
Goodbye.

Thank you.

How are you?

Hello.
```

I am very new in C# please help! Thanks!

Comment: btw; `StreamReader` is `IDisposable`; you should be `using` that, i.e. `using(var reader = new StreamReader("war.txt")) {...}`

Comment: This smells a lot like homework to me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do that, you are going to have to buffer the data *anyway* (unless you do some tricky work with the `FileStream` API to read the file backwards). How about just:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("war.txt");
for(int i = lines.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    Console.WriteLine(lines[i]);
```

which just loads the file (in lines) into an array, and then prints the array starting from the end.

A LINQ version of that would be:

```
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines("war.txt").Reverse())
    Console.WriteLine(line);
```

but frankly the array version is more efficient.

Comment: (note: `File.ReadLines` is .NET 4.0 and above)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using recursion with something like this:

```
void printReverse(int n)
{
   String line = reader.readLine();

   if (n > 0)
     printReverse(n-1);

   System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: For any non-trivial file, that is likely to blow the stack.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
File.ReadAllLines(myFile)
    .Reverse();
```

full code

```
var list =  File.ReadAllLines(filepath).Reverse().ToList();
           foreach (var l in list)
               Console.WriteLine(l);
```

Implementation detail

[Enumerable.Reverse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358497.aspx) - Inverts the order of the elements in a sequence

[File.ReadAllLines Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) - Opens a text file, reads all lines of the file, and then closes the file.

Comment: Why are you splitting on space?

Comment: @MarcGravell - i thought so i removed it there is no need of it

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at adding the lines to a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), then using [Reverse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2.aspx) on the list and then maybe the [ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) to output the items.

Answer (score 0):

Another option: store each line into a `Stack` as you read them. After reading the file, pop the stack to print the lines in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

with the enumerable extension functions, this can be done shorter:

```
foreach(var l in File.ReadAllLines("war.txt").Reverse())
    Console.WriteLine(l);
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a example mate, remember to add "using System.IO"

try

```
        {
            const int Size = 7;
            decimal[] numbers = new decimal[Size];
            decimal total = 0m;

            int index = 0;

            StreamReader inputfile;

            inputfile = File.OpenText("Sales.txt");

            while (index < numbers.Length && !inputfile.EndOfStream)
            {
                numbers[index] = decimal.Parse(inputfile.ReadLine());
                index++;
            }

            inputfile.Close();

            foreach (decimal Sales in numbers)
            {
                outputlistBox1.Items.Add(Sales);
                total = total + Sales;
            }

            textBox1.Text = total.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example from a textbook i bought few years ago, this has highest/lowest/average scores..(remember to use 'using System IO;)

private double Average(int[] iArray)

```
    {
        int total = 0;
        double Average;

        for (int index = 0; index < iArray.Length;
            index++)
       {
            total += iArray[index];
       }

        Average = (double) total / iArray.Length;

        return Average;
    }

    private int Highest(int[] iArray)
    {
        int highest = iArray[0];

        for (int index = 1; index < iArray.Length; index++)
        {
            if (iArray[index] > highest)
            {
                highest = iArray[index];
            }
        }

        return highest;
    }

    private int Lowest(int[] iArray)
    {
        int lowest = iArray[0];

        for (int index = 1; index < iArray.Length; index++)
        {
            if (iArray[index] < lowest)
            {
                lowest = iArray[index];
            }
        }

        return lowest;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            const int SIZE = 5;
            int[] Scores = new int [SIZE];
            int index = 0;
            int highestScore;
            int lowestScore;
            double averageScore;
            StreamReader inputFile;

            inputFile = File.OpenText("C:\\Users\\Asus\\Desktop\\TestScores.txt");

            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream && index < Scores.Length)
            {
                Scores[index] = int.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
                index++;
            }

            inputFile.Close();

            foreach (int value in Scores)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(value);
            }

            highestScore = Highest(Scores);
            lowestScore = Lowest(Scores);
            averageScore = Average(Scores);

            textBox1.Text = highestScore.ToString();
            textBox2.Text = lowestScore.ToString();
            textBox3.Text = averageScore.ToString("n1");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }      
}
```

}